# update statement using in equijoin

Tags: sql

I have two tables `TABLE1` contains columns `(deptno,sal)` and `TABLE2` contains columns `(deptno and location)` now I want to update 1000 more salary in the `sal` column for those persons that are working in `PARIS`(location column table 2) could you please answer me how I can do the update?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE t1 SET t1.sal = t1.sal+1000 
From Table1 as t1 INNER JOIN Table2 as t2 On t1.deptno = t2.deptno
WHERE t2.location = 'PARIS'
```